# Pass Javascript value into C# Code Behind (Scanning)

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I've got a scanner that calls a JavaScript function when it scans a barcode. In this function, I am trying to pass the barcode value into some kind of variable that I can use in my C# code behind. I've tried this:

```
document.getElementById("hidden").value = data;
alert(document.getElementById("hidden").value);
```

This gets the barcode value scanned and alerts it. In the code behind, I am looking for something like this:

```
protected void hidden_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//magic wizard man stuff going on
}
```

This doesn't seem to trigger at all. Any ideas?

(Essentially I want a value to get passed into C# Code Behind so I can do stuff with it)

Comment: as far as I know I'm pretty sure you need to you use Ajax in this situation because you can't pass something between client and server side without sending http request to the server.

Comment: ` __doPostBack('hiddenfieldid', parameter)` try this after changing the value of hiddenfield.

Comment: Did you tried put your hidden field run at server?

Comment: @Justcode Exactly what does this do?

Comment: @AlbertoMonteiro Yes it has the attribute.

Comment: So try what @Justcode said

Comment: initially browser won't postback if you change values at client side. you need to force it.

Comment: @Justcode I am still kind of stuck. I did __doPostBack('hidden',data), but I don't really know what to do with it.

Comment: @MarcusSvensson just add `__doPostBack('btn','');` after changing the hidden fields value replace your hiddenfields clientId with btn. and let me know

Answer (score 0):

You must do a postback eventually, but if you are ok with create a button and click it from your javascript code, that might be an easier solution.

Answer (score 0):

Attach that event to hidden field like this

```
<asp:hiddenfield id="hidden"
              onvaluechanged="hidden_ValueChanged"
              value="" 
              runat="server"/>
```

[MSDN source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield.valuechanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve this, you can use, Page Method. The other alternate is to use jquery, like this(just a code snippet):

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "WebForm.aspx/CodeBehindMethod",
          data: "{<your scanner id>}",
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          async: true,
          cache: false,
success: function (msg) 
        {
                       //any div or label you want to update
                }
              })
```

And in your code behind:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string CodeBehindMethod(string Id)
{
   //whatever you want to do with the Id
   return Id;
}
```